# How do I exclude a directory using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I asked a question a little while ago about using regular expressions to extract a match from a URL in a particular directory.

eg: `www.domain.com/shop/widgets/match/`

The solution given was `^/shop.*/([^/]+)/?$`

This would return `"match"`

However, my file structure has changed and I now need an expression that instead returns `"match"` in any directory excluding `"pages"` and `"system"`

Basically I need an expression that will return `"match"` for the following:

```
www.domain.com/shop/widgets/match/
www.domain.com/match/
```

But not:

```
www.domain.com/pages/widgets/match/
www.domain.com/pages/

www.domain.com/system/widgets/match/
www.domain.com/system/
```

I've been struggling for days without any luck.

Thanks

Comment: why not just use two regex's, the one you have now, and one to check to see if the word "pages" or "system" is in the URL.

Comment: `^/shop.*/([^/]+)/?$` would not match `www.domain.com/shop/widgets/match/` at all.  It would, however, match `/shop/widgets`.  You could use `/^[a-z0-9.-]+\/shop\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/$/` to extract "match" from that URL segment as `\1`.  I'm escaping the slashes because I'm also using slashes as delimiters.  If you don't need delimiters, you won't need to escape slashes.

Comment: @jb Hey, that's a good idea. I'll give that a go. But I am keen to see how it's done in a single expression.

Comment: @Matt, IMHO often when a single regex accomplishes two tasks it is "clever" but overly complex and very hard to read. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an alternative to Grahams great answer above. Code in C# (but fot the regex part, that doesn't matter):

```
void MatchDemo()
{
    var reg = new Regex("(                  "   +
                        "   (\\w+[.])       "   +
                        "   |               "   +
                        "   (\\w+[/])+      "   +
                        ")                  "   +
                        "(shop[/]|\\w+[/])  "   +               //the URL-string must contain the sequence "shop"
                        "(match)            "   ,
                        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    var url = @"www.domain.com/shop/widgets/match/";

    var retVal = reg.Match(url).Groups[5];                      //do we have anything in the fifth parentheses?

    Console.WriteLine(retVal);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

/Hans

Answer (score 2):

BRE and ERE do not provide a way to negate a portion of the RE, except within a square bracket expression. That is, you can `[^a-z]`, but you can't express *not `/(abc|def)/`*.  If your regex dialiect is ERE, then you *must* use two regexps.  If you're using PREG, you can use a negative look-ahead.

For example, here's some PHP:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$re = '/^www\.example\.com\/(?!(system|pages)\/)([^\/]+\/)*([^\/]+)\/$/';

$test = array(
    'www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/match/',
    'www.example.com/shop/widgets/match/',
    'www.example.com/match/',
    'www.example.com/pages/widgets/match/',
    'www.example.com/pages/',
    'www.example.com/system/widgets/match/',
    'www.example.com/system/',
);

foreach ($test as $one) {
    preg_match($re, $one, $matches);
    printf(">> %-50s\t%s\n", $one, $matches[3]);
}
```

And the output:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./phptest
>> www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/match/                   match
>> www.example.com/shop/widgets/match/                  match
>> www.example.com/match/                               match
>> www.example.com/pages/widgets/match/                 
>> www.example.com/pages/                               
>> www.example.com/system/widgets/match/                
>> www.example.com/system/
```

Is that what you're looking for?